# Let users edit their Laravel 5.6 blade view files

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

What are the risks of letting users edit their laravel blade views in order for them to edit the theme they are using?
Each user will have a folder created for them in the views folder containing their template made of blade.php files. There they can edit the html and access the $php_variables to display. Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Never do that, if you let a user have write access to a blade, he/she can do anything to your laravel project, literally anything, like letting in a thief in your house and tell him you can rob me.

Comment: `@php exec("rm -rf /") @endphp` By the way it goes without saying but do not actually paste this code in a blade file to see what it does in case it actually works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all there is the risk that your user creates vulnerabilities unintentionally. In example, if he does not escape an output correctly, another user could inject a malicious script (XSS) and then exploit your application. For laravel, this could happen by using {!! !!} instead of {{ }}.

Then there is the risk that your users wants to exploit your application himself by adding malicious code. Since blade templates are php files, he could do anything. And don't forget that he could execute javascript too.

Without knowing any more, it is hard to find a better solution. Depending on what your application is supposed to do, you should adapt the security.

For max security, i would filter the submitted content and delete all javascript and php, except for {{}}. For {{}}, check that the variables inside are allowed (create a list with allowed variable). Also make sure that he can not execute any other code inside the {{}}.

Block any external (and maybe even internal) link calls, since an attacker could load malicious script from another server/source. This goes for `<img>, <link>` etc... And no, it is not enough to simply block some file extensions.

Please read the [blade doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade) and make sure any other way for code execution is blocked, i.e.

```
@php
//
@endphp
```

If you want to create such a filter, check out [this link](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/2189-PHP-Filter-out-unwanted-PHP-Javascript-HTML-tags-.html), maybe it will help you to start. Please do a lot of research in order to be sure that you application is secure. And don't forget to secure the rest of you application too ;-)

Also check out the OWASP [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

EDIT: Of course there are several other ways to handle this. You could review each template yourself (if there are limited users), you could let the user choose between multiple templates (no edit), you could block all php&javascript and use "shortcodes" which you then replace by your controlled php code(basically your own template engine) etc.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I did find a solution using [Liquid](https://packagist.org/packages/liquid/liquid)